# Vibrator.vibrate(long) causing frequent application restarts on LG-E730

Tags: android, vibration

If I am using the Vibrator.vibrate(long) on an LG-E370 this is causing frequent application restarts. The vibrator permission has been added to the manifest and the vibrator vibrates up to 5 times before the app is restarting.

How can I vibrate reliably?

I added the output of a stacktrace to my onPause() and this is what I get:

```
04-02 14:39:36.384:  dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(Native Method)
04-02 14:39:36.384:  java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:737)
04-02 14:39:36.384:  com.evotegra.aCoDriver.ACoDriverActivity.onPause(ACoDriverActivity.java:94)
04-02 14:39:36.384:  android.app.Activity.performPause(Activity.java:3851)
04-02 14:39:36.384:  android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPause(Instrumentation.java:1191)
04-02 14:39:36.424:  android.app.ActivityThread.performNewIntents(ActivityThread.java:1747)
04-02 14:39:36.424:  android.app.ActivityThread.handleNewIntent(ActivityThread.java:1757)
04-02 14:39:36.424:  android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:117)
04-02 14:39:36.424:  android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:989)
04-02 14:39:36.424:  android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-02 14:39:36.434:  android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
04-02 14:39:36.434:  android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3740)
04-02 14:39:36.434:  java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-02 14:39:36.434:  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-02 14:39:36.444:  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:880)
04-02 14:39:36.444:  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:638)
04-02 14:39:36.444:  dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

04-02 14:39:44.351:  dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(Native Method)
04-02 14:39:44.371:  java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:737)
04-02 14:39:44.371:  com.evotegra.aCoDriver.ACoDriverActivity.onPause(ACoDriverActivity.java:94)
04-02 14:39:44.371:  android.app.Activity.performPause(Activity.java:3851)
04-02 14:39:44.381:  android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPause(Instrumentation.java:1191)
04-02 14:39:44.381:  android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2356)
04-02 14:39:44.381:  android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2326)
04-02 14:39:44.381:  android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2818)
04-02 14:39:44.401:  android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:117)
04-02 14:39:44.401:  android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:946)
04-02 14:39:44.411:  android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-02 14:39:44.411:  android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
04-02 14:39:44.411:  android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3740)
04-02 14:39:44.462:  java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-02 14:39:44.462:  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-02 14:39:44.462:  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:880)
04-02 14:39:44.482:  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:638)
04-02 14:39:44.492:  dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-02 14:39:44.772: W/ServerManager(8731): <!>com.evotegra.aCoDriver.data.ServerManager$ConnectionManager 559<!> Connection thread was interrupted. Message: null
04-02 14:39:44.862:  dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(Native Method)
04-02 14:39:44.862:  java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:737)
04-02 14:39:44.862:  com.evotegra.aCoDriver.ACoDriverActivity.onPause(ACoDriverActivity.java:94)
04-02 14:39:44.862:  android.app.Activity.performPause(Activity.java:3851)
04-02 14:39:44.862:  android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPause(Instrumentation.java:1191)
04-02 14:39:44.862:  android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2356)
04-02 14:39:44.862:  android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2326)
04-02 14:39:44.862:  android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2818)
04-02 14:39:44.872:  android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:117)
04-02 14:39:44.872:  android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:946)
04-02 14:39:44.872:  android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-02 14:39:44.872:  android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
04-02 14:39:44.872:  android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3740)
04-02 14:39:44.872:  java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-02 14:39:44.872:  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-02 14:39:44.872:  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:880)
04-02 14:39:44.872:  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:638)
04-02 14:39:44.872:  dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-02 14:39:48.315:  dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(Native Method)
04-02 14:39:48.315:  java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:737)
04-02 14:39:48.315:  com.evotegra.aCoDriver.ACoDriverActivity.onPause(ACoDriverActivity.java:94)
04-02 14:39:48.315:  android.app.Activity.performPause(Activity.java:3851)
04-02 14:39:48.315:  android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPause(Instrumentation.java:1191)
04-02 14:39:48.325:  android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2356)
04-02 14:39:48.335:  android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2326)
04-02 14:39:48.345:  android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2306)
04-02 14:39:48.345:  android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:117)
04-02 14:39:48.345:  android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:953)
04-02 14:39:48.355:  android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-02 14:39:48.355:  android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
04-02 14:39:48.355:  android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3740)
04-02 14:39:48.355:  java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-02 14:39:48.375:  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-02 14:39:48.375:  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:880)
04-02 14:39:48.375:  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:638)
04-02 14:39:48.385:  dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: The stacktrace seems unrelated to the vibration. Also, you left out the exception name.

Comment: There is no exception. Only for some reason OnPause() is called. If I turn on Vibration it is restarting after max 5 vibrations. If I turn it off it runs forever.

Comment: Does it work fine on other devices?

Comment: Works fine on Samsung and HTC. No restarts there.

Comment: Seems to be a device bug then. Not much you can do about it. If you really want to confirm it, see if there's a cyanogen ROM for your LG device and install that and try out your app. If it works fine, its a bug on LG's side.